# Copy a subset of xml from one column to another on sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a table (on sqlserver05) with an xml column. The format of the column is similar to this:

```
<doc>
   <field name="a">foo</field>
   <field name="b">bar</field>
   <field name="c">fizz</field>
   <field name="d">buzz</field>
</doc>
```

I would like to copy a subset of that xml to a new xml column, for instance:

```
<doc>
   <field name="a">foo</field>
   <field name="c">fizz</field>
</doc>
```

How can I do so?

EDIT: this is what worked for me (based on the accepted answer)

```
UPDATE tbl
SET xml_SubColumn = 
    xml_Column.query('<doc>{//field[@name="a" or @name="c"]}</doc>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XQuery:

```
declare @x xml;
set @x = '<doc>
   <field name="a">foo</field>
   <field name="b">bar</field>
   <field name="c">fizz</field>
   <field name="d">buzz</field>
</doc>';

select @x.query('<doc>{//field[@name="a" or @name="c"]}</doc>');
```

In your case apply the xquery to the XML column. Of course, adapt the XQuery to your specific case, my expression is just an example that assumes that your criteria is `@name='a' or @name='b'`.

Comment: I modified what you gave me to add an UPDATE clause, and it worked perfect. Thanks!